# couldnt get output in python program

Tags: python

```
while True:
    n = int (input ("What's n? "))
    if n > 0:
        break

    for _ in range(n):
        print("meow")
```

I can enter the input, but I could receive the output and I didn't have any error in my terminal window, please help where I went wrong.

Comment: Do you know what `break` does?

Comment: That's because you're breaking out of the loop before printing.

Comment: you said "gimme a break" in your program, so it refused to print and say meow

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is inside your `while` loop and after the `if` statement. When your `if` statement evaluates to `True` (i.e. n > 0) then the `break` instruction will cause the program to exit the `while` loop.  Thus, your `for` loop will never be executed.

You can learn more about the break statement from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm#:%7E:text=The%20break%20statement%20in%20Python,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops.).

> The **`break`** statement in Python terminates the current loop and resumes
> execution at the next statement

You can fix your code by moving the `for` loop outside of the `while` loop as follows:

```
while True:
    n = int(input("What's n? "))
    if n > 0:
        break

for _ in range(n):
    print('meow')
```

Comment: Did you type in an integer? The error message suggests you typed in an ampersand (&) character.

Comment: yes, after i run the program, my input got displayed what's n and i gave my input number called 2, then i got an error.

Comment: @MurugeshwariRavi Are you sure? Your computer seems convinced you typed `&`.

Comment: yep, I only gave numbers.

Comment: Then something strange is going on with your terminal input or your keyboard or something, and that sounds like a new question.